# How can I record the username and timestamp of row insertions and updates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to record the last user and last time a particular row was either inserted or updated in a MySQL table. What is the best way to go about this? Is there some MySQL metadata I can investigate or do I need to create username and timestamp columns myself and then create triggers to populate them?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "last user"?

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ The logged-in MySQL user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in MySQL 5.5.46, you can track tables. This includes structure and data. There, the DB username and timestamp is recorded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create separate columns yourself for timestamp and user name. For timestamps there is no need to use triggers to update its value, just declare the timestamp field to use current timestamp as initial value and update value:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

The user is bit more interesting. If you are talking about mysql level user, then yes, use triggers or stored procedure using the [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_user) function. If you are talking about application level users, then I would supply that username as part of the update statement.

```
UPDATE table SET username='xxx', ... WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use a column and set it default system date for insert
- For update you must use trigger or etcs.